# undefined method `attributes' for GroupItem:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to make a new feature to work. I have wrote the following class:

```
class ::GroupItem
  attributes :group_enabled,
             :list_count

  def group_enabled
    true
  end

  def include_group_enabled?
    Topic.group_enabled object
  end

  def list_count
    object.list_count
  end

  def include_list_count?
    include_group_enabled?
  end
end
```

I run `bundle exec puma` and for some reason I get the following error:

```
! Unable to load application: NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for GroupItem:Class
Did you mean?  attr_writer
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/puma)
NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for GroupItem:Class
Did you mean?  attr_writer
```

The strange part is that when I replace the first line with:

```
 ::GroupItem.class_eval do # instead of class ::GroupItem
```

It works. What is the problem? How should I solve it?

Comment: I guess you forgot to make an inheritance class for the class as the errors showed

Comment: Did you try using `attr_accessor :group_enabled, :list_count` or `attr_writer :group_enabled, :list_count` instead of `attributes :group_enabled, :list_count`?

Comment: declaring a class as `class ::GroupItem` is pretty wierd. Mainly because if you just declare a constant without nesting it in a module it will be nested in Main (the global namespace). `::` just signifies that you want to resolve the constant from main instead of the current module nesting (and even then declaring a constant outside of the current nesting is wierd).